# Why doesn't angular-table (see angulartable.com) properly support being included via ng-include?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

The very busy author of the [angular-table directive](http://angulartable.com) suggested I post this question here:

Can anyone see why angular-table doesn't properly support being included via ng-include?

See example at http://plnkr.co/edit/6hC9NIDPxPl9IPX9FzcE?p=info .

(Here a sample inline table that properly renders is followed by an ng-included version of the same table that doesn't properly render).

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem to accept running 2 instances within one controller. Simple workaround is use 2 controllers and share data/methods through a service

```
app.factory('TableData',function(){      
  return  [{name: 'John'}, {name: 'Bill'}, {name: 'Sam'}, 
                            {name: 'Dave'}, {name: 'Phil'}, {name: 'Mike'}, 
                            {name: 'Tim'}, {name: 'Jack'}, {name: 'Ron'}];
  });


app.controller('TableController1', ['$scope','TableData',
  function($scope, TableData) {
    $scope.names =TableData
  }
]);

app.controller('TableController2', ['$scope','TableData',
  function($scope, TableData) {
    $scope.names =TableData
  }
]);
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/T4NmI6gtvtPpUjUssymY?p=preview)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Gamb but that turned out to not be the problem, though you certainly pointed the way to the actual one: namely, that the ng-included table would only inherit the higher level controller if it was wrapped inside a standard html parent element (eg. div) within the ng-included file.

Try uncommenting the  element in name-table.html in the revised version of my plunk to see what I mean.

Thanks nevertheless for steering me in the right direction, Gamb!